# I want to put a list on a string

Tags: python, html, string

I'm getting a png file name from a file then and using regex to specify a 4 digit number png file name, removing the punctuations marks and saving it to another file

What has stumped me was trying to put every individual value on the list in a string like:

```
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="images/char/{HERE}.png" ></div>
```

And then save it to the file as:

```
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="images/char/1432.png" ></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="images/char/1250.png" ></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="images/char/1324.png" ></div>
```

This is the code

```
import re
import pyperclip

def remove_punc(string):
    punc = '''!()-[]{};:'"\, <>./?@#$%^&*_~'''
    for ele in string:  
        if ele in punc:  
            string = string.replace(ele, "") 
    return string
 



text_file = open(r'C:\My Web Sites\‏‏image_data(1).txt', 'r') 
    
s = text_file.read()

text_file.close()
string_pattern = r"\d{4}\." 


regex_pattern = re.compile(string_pattern)


# find all the matches in string one
result = regex_pattern.findall(s)

result = [remove_punc(i) for i in result]


with open(r'C:\My Web Sites\1.txt', 'w') as fp:
    for item in result:
        # write each item on a new line
        fp.write("%s\n" % item)
        

fp.close()
```

EDIT

This is a sample of the text file

```
<div class="cell-imgs"><div class="character-thumbnail"><img src="resources/images/bgs/5.png" class="character-thumbnail-background"><img class="character-thumbnail-image" src="resources/images/thumb/1535.png" onerror="this.src='resources/images/thumb/noimage.png';"><img rel="popover" tabindex="0" src="resources/images/frames/5.png" class="character-thumbnail-frame" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Rarity: 5★<br/>Level: 1/60<br/>Level: 0/4<br/>Level: 1/5<br/>: 0%" title="" data-original-title="<font color='red'><br/>(version)</font>"><img src="resources/images/elements/3.png" class="character-thumbnail-element"></div><div class="character-thumbnail"><img src="resources/images/bgs/5.png" class="character-thumbnail-background"><img class="character-thumbnail-image" src="resources/images/thumb/1510.png" onerror="this.src='resources/images/thumb/noimage.png';"><img rel="popover" tabindex="1" src="resources/images/frames/5.png" class="character-thumbnail-frame" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Rarity: 5★<br/>Level: 1/80<br/>Level: 4/4<br/>Level: 1/5<br/>: 0%" title="" data-original-title="<font color='#F96700'><br/>(version)</font>"><img src="resources/images/elements/5.png" class="character-thumbnail-element"></div><div class="character-thumbnail"><img src="resources/images/bgs/5.png" class="character-thumbnail-background"><img class="character-thumbnail-image" src="resources/images/thumb/1403.png" onerror="this.src='resources/images/thumb/noimage.png';"><img rel="popover" tabindex="2" src="resources/images/frames/5.png" class="character-thumbnail-frame" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Rarity: 5★<br/>Level: 1/80<br/>Level: 4/4<br/>Level: 1/5<br/>: 0%" title="" data-original-title="<font color='#071BA0'><br/>(version)</font>"><img src="resources/images/elements/4.png" class="character-thumbnail-element"></div><div class="character-thumbnail"><img src="resources/images/bgs/5.png" class="character-thumbnail-background"><img class="character-thumbnail-image" src="resources/images/thumb/1388.png" onerror="this.src='resources/images/thumb/noimage.png';"><img rel="popover" tabindex="3" src="resources/images/frames/5.png" class="character-thumbnail-frame" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Rarity: 5★<br/>Level: 1/80<br/>Level: 4/4<br/>Level: 1/5<br/>: 0%" title="" data-original-title="<font color='#F96700'><br/>(version)</font>"><img src="resources/images/elements/5.png" class="character-thumbnail-element"></div><div class="character-thumbnail"><img src="resources/images/bgs/6.png" class="character-thumbnail-background"><img class="character-thumbnail-image" src="resources/images/thumb/1323.png" onerror="this.src='resources/images/thumb/noimage.png';"><img rel="popover" tabindex="4" src="resources/images/frames/6.png" class="character-thumbnail-frame" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content="Rarity: 6★<br/>Level: 200/200<br/>Level: 4/4<br/>Level: 1/5<br/>: 150%<br/>1: 0/10<br/>2: 0/10<br/>3: 0/10<br/>" title="<font color='red'><br/>(version)</font>"><img src="resources/images/elements/3.png" class="character-thumbnail-element"></div><div class="character-thumbnail"><img src="resources/images/bgs/5.png" class="character-thumbnail-background"><img class="character-thumbnail-image" src="resources/images/thumb/1322.png"
```

Output

```
1535
1510
1403
1388
1323
1322
```

Comment: What is your current output? What is `remove_punc`? Also provide a sample of your text file.

Comment: assuming file_1 as the file which contains the numbers and file_2 contains the formal output expected, file_1 only have 4 numbers per line or can have another inputs?

Comment: remove_punc removes the punctuations  marks @not_speshal

Comment: file one is full of HTML code and the .py extract the names of the images which comprise of 4 digits number and a period, which is saved on file_1, and than write on file_2 as 4 digits per line.
File_1 has 166 matches with the regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create your file you can use [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). For example:

```py
s = """<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="images/char/{}.png"></div>"""

result = [1432, 1250, 1324]  # <-- your result with removed punctuations

with open("data.txt", "w") as fp:
    for item in result:
        print(s.format(item), file=fp)
```

creates `data.txt` with content:

```html
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="images/char/1432.png"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="images/char/1250.png"></div>
<div class="parent"><img class="img" title="" src="images/char/1324.png"></div>
```

Comment: I knew that I can do it, but didn't know where to start and what to search for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Given more info about the author [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72165342/i-want-to-put-a-list-on-a-string#comment127505188_72165342)

This pattern should do the trick `(\d{4})\.(?=png)`
Where

- Captures digits exactly at 4 times
- And ends with .png

If you want to add support for example with jpeg you can change the pattern to `(\d{4})\.(?=png|jpeg)`

For online testing i coded this, but it should work loading the file then using findall. The rest of the job is yours.

```
import re

string = "<div class=\"parent\"><img class=\"img\" title=\"\" src=\"images/char/1432.png\" ></div>\n<div class=\"parent\"><img class=\"img\" title=\"\" src=\"images/char/1250.png\" ></div>\n<div class=\"parent\"><img class=\"img\" title=\"\" src=\"images/char/1324.png\" ></div>\n<div class=\"parent\"><img class=\"img\" title=\"\" src=\"images/char/1324.jpeg\" ></div>"

pattern = re.compile(r'(\d{4})\.(?=png)')

print(pattern.findall(string))
```

where the output is

`['1432', '1250', '1324']`